# How to correctly implode array to achieve REGEXP within mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo, prepared-statement

I am having difficulties to correctly implode an array into REGEXP to use it within mySQL. If I have only 1 item in the array, the results are returned as expected. However, if I have multiple items in the array, as the following example:

```
Array ( [url0] => get-started [url1] => contact )
```

I don't get the expected results

It seems like I am having an error in this line but I can not figure it out:

```
   WHERE url REGEXP (:' . implode('| :', array_keys($params)) . ')';
```

the desired is to work like this:

```
WHERE url REGEXP (:url0| :url1)
WHERE url REGEXP ('get-started|contact')
```

Thank you

UPDATE - EXTRA CODE

```
$params = [];
foreach ($urls as $idx => $url) {
                $params['url' . $idx] = $url;
            }

url REGEXP (:' . implode('| :', array_keys($params)) . ')';
```

Comment: What is the status of this question? None of the provided answers work?

Answer (score 4):

You could either implode the array to a string in PHP, and bind that to one SQL query parameter:

```
$urls = implode('|', $params);

$sql = 'SELECT ... WHERE url REGEXP :urls';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute( [ 'urls' => $urls ] );
```

Or you could make each array element a SQL query parameter, and implode them in SQL using [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

```
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE url REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute( $params );
```

You need as many `?` parameter placeholders as the number of elements in the array.

With PDO, you can use either named parameters or positional parameters, but don't use both in the same SQL query.

---

Regarding your comment about using named parameters:

I would not use named parameters for queries that have lists of values for  `IN ( )` or `REGEXP` the way you are using it. It's more trouble than it's worth. It would be simpler to use positional parameters in this case.

But to achieve what you want:

```
$keys = array_keys($params);
$keys_with_colons = array_map(function ($s) { return ":$s"; }, $keys);
$url_placeholders = implode(',', $keys_with_colons);
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE url REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', $url_placeholders)";
```

Comment: (Placeholder builder, I was writing up something similiar to this answer `implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));`

Comment: Yep, I've used that method too. I didn't want to clutter up the code in my answer.

Comment: I need to use my current structure as I do with url `IN(:' . implode(', :', array_keys($params)) . ')';` that works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `:url0` and `:url1` in

```
WHERE url REGEXP (:url0| :url1)
```

are placeholders for PDO. This will not bring you anywhere, since `|` is a bit-opreator (bitwise OR) and will return an integer (in most cases `0`).

The second (desired) example

```
WHERE url REGEXP ('get-started|contact')
```

is more reasonable. This can be constructed and executed as following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url REGEXP(:pattern)");
$stmt->execute(['pattern' => implode('|', $params)];
```

Comment: So I won't be able to use REGEXP with PDO ? I need to continue use it.

Comment: What do mean? I'm using REGEXP **with** PDO in my example.

Comment: I need to use my current structure as I do with url `IN(:' . implode(', :', array_keys($params)) . ')';` that works perfectly fine.

Comment: If it "works perfectly fine", then I don't understand what you are asking. See what I wrote about the `|` operator. Try `SELECT ('get-started' | 'contact')` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array ( 'url0' => 'get-started', 'url1' => 'contact' );
echo 'WHERE url REGEXP ("' . implode('|', ($params)) . '")';
```

Result:

```
WHERE url REGEXP ("get-started|contact")
```

Comment: The correct usage of the REGEXP is as `("get-started|contact")` without the additional double quotes

Comment: ok i edited : `echo 'WHERE url REGEXP ("' . implode('|', ($params)) . '")';`

Comment: This is not secure usage. It looks like OP is trying to use bound placeholders then binding the regex values later.

Comment: @MrFreezer since I am binding, I have to use that specific structure. I have updated my question with extra code

Comment: @MrFreezer I tried this and it gives me the correct results, however, it doesn't use the bindings as `:url0 :url1`